# Could not install packages due to an OSError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1131)

Tags: python, ssl, cacerts

I'been trying to sovle this problem by reading differents answers in here but none of them turn out to be "the solution",so I would try to breafly explain my situation so you guys can give me a clue.
The thing is that when I try to run `pip install <package>` it start with this warnings (just to show you, use as an example fastapi):

```
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1131)'))': /packages/4f/46/226355e82ccb4be82e06269e9a546f16c1d87fbda2286fb5d36a1c31af9e/fastapi-0.75.0-py3-none-any.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1131)'))': /packages/4f/46/226355e82ccb4be82e06269e9a546f16c1d87fbda2286fb5d36a1c31af9e/fastapi-0.75.0-py3-none-any.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1131)'))': /packages/4f/46/226355e82ccb4be82e06269e9a546f16c1d87fbda2286fb5d36a1c31af9e/fastapi-0.75.0-py3-none-any.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1131)'))': /packages/4f/46/226355e82ccb4be82e06269e9a546f16c1d87fbda2286fb5d36a1c31af9e/fastapi-0.75.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

And it ends with:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/4f/46/226355e82ccb4be82e06269e9a546f16c1d87fbda2286fb5d36a1c31af9e/fastapi-0.75.0-py3-none-any.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1,'[SSL:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate(_ssl.c:1131)')))
```

The first thing that I tried was `pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org <package>`, but it only gave me another error. So I started to read about SSL Certificates, and when the error says **self signed certificates** it means that the server that I'm trying to connect, his certificte is self-signed by the server itself or the entity that provides the chain signature is not in the *white list* of the browser.
[And in fact it is so!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDcC1.png).

But when I use some of the online tools to check the certificates for this site [everything seems to be reliable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2inj.png).

Context:

- Last time I download a package was about a month ago (I realize of this yesterday)
- Python version: 3.8.10 / pip version: 21.1.1
- Windows 10 / Personal machine and Home network (No company permissions)
- This happend at every level: when trying to build a docker, inside a `venv` and also at System level (outside venv)

So, I don't know where to start really. Is my local machine the problem?, is pythonhosted the problem?, Am I mixing things up?, Should I uninstall/re-install Python?

Answer (score 6):

Below command should solve your problem.

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org 
<package-name>
```

Eg:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org 
pandas
```

Comment: Awesome, this works. I had the same issue when I'm trying to install something from at home while when being in the company this doesn't occur. Could you please explain why that is and why your contribution works?